# (J2me) Stream as a buffer?

Tags: java, java-me, buffer, outputstream

Here I got a j2me application and I need to transmit or save live data from a output stream.

What could happen if I use one thread to write data to the stream and after writing certain no ofl bytes other thread to get a bytearray out of it save or transmit it and reset the stream to zero..

I.e calling reset on it .. This effectively equals to using stream as fixed size buffer..

The constrain here is that I may not be able to use the byteBuffer object for the purpose

will that make the stream invalid because the first thread is still wiring to it?

Comment: I only understand your first sentence. Try to rephrase your question; it's very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are going to use `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream` class, which is part of `CLDC 1.0` standard of J2ME.

CLDC 1.0 does not say anything about thread safety of `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

But if you look implementation of `ByteArrayOutputStream`, all needed methods seems to be `synchronized`:

```
public synchronized byte toByteArray()[] { ... }
public synchronized void reset() { ... }
public synchronized void write(byte b[], int off, int len) { ... }
```

If you have access to sources of your J2ME classes. You can double check that.

If methods are synchronized, then it should be safe to use stream as you plan.